# Open a Popup window without any close button

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, popupwindow

I have a webhierarchicaldatagrid and its first column is a template column which is a hyperlink. So onmouseover on the data of that column I want a small popup window to be open right next to that data so that user can drag the mouse on that popup window. The window contains few links which on click will navigate to another page. I want to know how to get the popup window to be open right next to the data and also how to keep it open only when the mouse is on it. as soon as the mouse is not on the popup I want the popup to close.

Comment: consider to use any existing jQuery popup window, if you google it you find a lot.

Answer (score 0):

qTip is a pretty popular jQuery plugin that can do what you are wanting.  Here is the demo page for the type of functionality you are describing:

[Demo Fixed tooltips on hover](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/position/fixed)

Here is another link, with 30 popular tooltip plugins:

[30 Stylish jQuery Tooltip Plugins For Catchy Designs](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/)